# Can you tell me how to apply the same PowerShell source to multiple folders?

Tags: powershell

I have a working PowerShell source.
However, you need to apply the same PowerShell source to multiple subfolders in the folder.

There is a "-" in the middle of the subfolder name.
There are hundreds of folders. I want to apply the PowerShell source at once. I haven't been studying PowerShell. Please let me know.

The PowerShell source to be applied is as follows.

```
$Subfolder=Get-location
$Fullname=(Split-path $Subfolder -Leaf).ToString();
$di=$Fullname.IndexOf("-");
$Fnametoend=$Fullname.SubString($di);
$Fnametoend=$Fnametoend.TrimStart("-")

foreach($dir in $Subfolder){
    $path=$Subfolder
    $dir
        Get-Childitem -Path $path -Filter "*.jpeg" -File |
            Group-Object -Property @{Expression = {$_.Fnametoend}}|
            ForEach-Object {
                $dir=$Fnametoend
                $nr=1
                foreach($file in $_.Group){
                    $file | Rename-item -Newname("{0}_2020_{1}.jpeg"-f $dir, $nr++)
                }
        }
}
```

There are numerous subfolders in the project folder, and jpeg files are in the subfolders.

When I enter the project folder and run PowerShell, I want to run the PowerShell source in each of the numerous subfolders.

This is an example picture of the project folder.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CNrm.png)

Like this, I would like to apply the PowerShell source that I have in a number of subfolders within the project folder.Unfortunately I am applying the powershell source by clicking the folders one by one.

I want to apply the PowerShell source to all folders at once. Can you help? I want to apply the powershell source to all folders at once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set the root folder to `Get-Location`, you will only have one single path (where the script is running from).
What you need to do is to define the path for the source folder and then iterate over all subfolders in there using `Get-ChildItem`.

In below code I have put a lot of code comments, so you should be able to follow every step it takes.

```
# enter the path to where all subfolders to process are.
$rootFolder = 'D:\Test'

# find all '*.jpeg' files in the subfolders. 
# -Depth 1 ensures it only searches in subfolders 1 level deep under the root folder.
# If these have subfolders of their own you need to go through, either remove '-Depth 1'
# or set a higher number of levels to search through.
Get-Childitem -Path $rootFolder -Filter "*.jpeg" -File -Recurse -Depth 1 |
    # make sure the folder the files are in has a hyphen in its name
    Where-Object { $_.Directory.Name -like '*-*' } |
    # group the found files on the last part after the '-' in the folder name
    Group-Object @{Expression = {($_.Directory.Name -split '-')[-1]}} |
    ForEach-Object {
        # $_.Name is the name of the group, which we set to ($_.Directory.Name -split '-')[-1]
        $nr = 1
        # loop through all files in the group and rename
        foreach($file in $_.Group){
            $file | Rename-item -Newname ("{0}_2020_{1}.jpeg"-f $_.Name, $nr++)
        }
    }
```

Example:

**before**

```
D:\TEST
+---ASWQ-12H4JV7S
|       AnotherPicture.jpeg
|       SomePicture.jpeg
|
\---QWEQ-8E8W4G44
        Arnold.jpeg
        Bruce.jpeg
        Lee.jpeg
        Schwartzenegger.jpeg
```

**after**

```
D:\TEST
+---ASWQ-12H4JV7S
|       12H4JV7S_2020_1.jpeg
|       12H4JV7S_2020_2.jpeg
|
\---QWEQ-8E8W4G44
        8E8W4G44_2020_1.jpeg
        8E8W4G44_2020_2.jpeg
        8E8W4G44_2020_3.jpeg
        8E8W4G44_2020_4.jpeg
```

Comment: Mr. Theo.
I have been very helpful to you in the last few days.
You have always helped to be specific. Thank you so much.

Comment: The code is perfect and it's the same purpose I want.

Comment: @AAron Thanks for the nice feedback. Please don't forget to accept the answer, so this question can be ticked off as `done`.